# asp.net mvc routing with $routeProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-routing, angular-routing

Is there any sane way to use these?

What I want to have - is a single page with a nav-menu and `<ng-view>` below it.
And all the routing should be angular's responsibility.

But, I'd like to keep mvc goodness as well. I like neatly organized server-side controllers and razor pages.

I can't access .cshtml directly though, so how do I access my templates?

I don't want the main page and its content to be reloaded ever. It loads once and after that, all the navigation to other pages should be loading associated templates only.

How can I achieve that?

I can't find a single thorough example how to use them together.

Answer (score 2):

Angular is used for single page web applications (SPAs).

ASP.NET MVC is used for server-side pages.

In ASP.NET MVC with Angular, your `Index.cshtml` or whatever your main view page is will contain all your JavaScripts and load your Angular app.  You shouldn't ever navigate away from that page again.  Angular's router just changes the URL (using a hash) and rebuilds the DOM based on the route.

They aren't supposed to "work together" for navigation.  The only way they work together is if you create a REST API (or any API I suppose) with MVC and access it through Angular ($http, $resource, etc).

Comment: ok.. but then aspnetMVC has to have at least one route, let's say we keep the default route, make _ViewStart.cshtml "main page", configure $routeProvider to get templates, but then you're gonna need to write an action method that returns a view, you can't just use templateUrl directly - the file won't be accessible directly...

Comment: and how is it possible to constrain asp.net from navigation to other controller\actions?

Comment: Angular navigates using the hash - `/#/posts/123`.  The server ASP.NET routes never actually change.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this project https://github.com/kazimanzurrashid/my-walletz-angular/blob/master/source/MyWalletz/Views/Home/Index.cshtml#L11 (shameless plug i am the owner) there is a helper method called IncludeClientView which inlines all the client side templates in the view. If you want to dynamically load the templates then create a controller and pass the template name from the client, then in the controller use partial view to return the template.

Answer (score 1):

please install the AngularJS SPA Template from visual studio>> extensions and updates .